# Get top n records for each group of grouped results with Bigquery (standard SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results), which is almost exactly what I want. But I can't get it working on Bigquery with standard SQL because BQ doesn't allow user defined variables.

**Note** - I have an arbitrary number of groups, so `UNION`ing all of them as per the first answer in the linked question is not feasible.

> The following is the simplest possible example, though any solution
>   should be able to scale to however many n top results are needed:
>
> Given a table like that below, with person, group, and age columns,
>   how would you get the 2 oldest people in each group? (Ties within
>   groups should not yield more results, but give the first 2 in any
>   order)

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Person | Group | Age |
+--------+-------+-----+
| Bob    | 1     | 32  |
| Jill   | 1     | 34  |
| Shawn  | 1     | 42  |
| Jake   | 2     | 29  |
| Paul   | 2     | 36  |
| Laura  | 2     | 39  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

> Desired result set:

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Shawn  | 1     | 42  |
| Jill   | 1     | 34  |
| Laura  | 2     | 39  |
| Paul   | 2     | 36  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

One answer in the linked question mentions using `ROW_NUMBER` which does exist, but I can't work out how to restart the number for each group.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group order by age desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

`row_number()` is an ANSI standard window function.  It is available in most databases.  In general, I would suggest that you look more for solutions using Postgres rather than MySQL for solving problems in BQ (if you can't find a BQ resource itself).

Answer (score 10):

You can use `ARRAY_AGG` with a limit. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  `Group`,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Person, Age)
            ORDER BY Age DESC LIMIT 2) AS oldest_people
FROM People
GROUP BY `Group`;
```